# Escaping curly braces in C string

Tags: c, string, curly-braces

I'm doing my first exercises in C and would like to do the following:

The program running in combination with my C code reads inputs in the following format (I cannot change that):

> {"inputname":0}

My C code is supposed to read the string from a command line input. If I enter the exact form quoted above, it works fine. However, putting curly braces in the command line is annoying (my program will not let me write them, for example).

So I would like to piece the input together, and put the braces around it automatically inside the code, so the input from the command window needs only be **"inputname":0** instead of **{"inputname":0}**.

When I try just putting the three strings **{**, **input** and **}** together I get

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[200]’ from type
>   ‘char *’

as soon as I add the second bracer.

So how do I do it?

Comment: How do you "put together" these strings? C has no string operators like `+`, `.`or `~` for concatenation. You likely want something along the lines of  `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "{%s}", input)` depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: So please show HOW you are putting your substrings together.

Comment: Sorry: Putting them together via 
`char inbraces[200]`
`char outbraces[200]` 
`char inputstring[200]` 
`strcpy(inbraces, "{");`
`strcpy(outbraces, "}");`
`strcat(inputstring, outbraces)`
so far it works perfectly. But when I add the second braces, so that the new string has braces on both sides, it produces this error.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; edit your question instead. You're giving us the code that works, but fail to show the piece of code that produces the error ("When I add the second braces"). Please try to be comprehensive in your problem description: Post the relevant code and idicate where the error occurs.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the code that causes the error, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also mark out the line where you get the error.

Comment: I just got it to work while producing the minimal example. When I find out why it works now and why it didn't work before, I'll put it in here. Thank you for your help and sorry :).

Comment: @Anphie That is actually one of the purposes of creating such an example, because more often than not one will find the problem by one-self. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note: All of this is *guessing* after reading the error message.

---

The error is saying that you can't assign to an array, basically. For example if you have e.g.

```
char string[200];
```

then you can't do

```
string = "Foobar";
```

or

```
const char *open_brace = "{";
string = open_brace;
```

If you want to set an array, you have to *copy* to it, using the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

```
strcpy(string, "Foobar");
```

or

```
strcpy(string, open_brace);
```

If you then want to append something to your string, you *concatenate* another string using [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat):

```
const char close_brace = "}";
strcat(string, close_brace);
```

The above appends the string `"}"` at the end of the array `string`.

Be careful though, so you don't overflow the array and write out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I should have been more elaborate in my original question. I know that strings need to be concatenated, the problem is that the above mentioned error occurs when I concatenate the second brace to the string, so that the string is enclosed in braces.